# jquery autocomplete multipleSeparator case sensitive

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I would like to use the case-sensitive word as multiple separator for autocomplete.

right now, I am using separator as "AND".

```
multipleSeparator : " AND ",
```

Can I make it case-sensitive.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you using, and which version is it?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720062/jquery-autocomplete-multiple-separator-array

Comment: Try to google for "jquery.autocomplete" and tell me how many plugins you can see.... Provide a link to specific plugin.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete, This is the plugin I am using.

Comment: you should put some html in your jsfiddle, so we can actually have a play around with it :)

Comment: Actually to play around, the code I pasted is not having any sample array items hardcoded. Sorry for that. Those files I use are directly from my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer in easy way,

Before splitting the words with multiple seperator,
I replaced all the areas of multipleTerm value to Upper Case.

```
value = value.replace(/ and /ig, " AND ");
```

Thanks guys for your effort.